# Change grid refund magento

Tags: magento-1.8, backend

I actually wanna add sub total, total excluding tax and sub total including tax in my refunded grid in the admin backend of magento (sales->Refunded, the 4th one). I don't have any idea of how I can do it. The only I know is that I will copy a core file in local to extend this.

Thanks a lot for your help =) -> I'm on Magento 1.8.1

EDIt:
Finally found the file I need to change :
`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Sales/Refunded/Grid.php`
But still don't know what I need to change in, because when I change others grid, I need to extend _prepareCollection() and add some attributes in _prepareColumns(), but in Refunded/Grid.php, there is no _prepareCollection(), so I'm in trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad idea to edit the file directly.
I'll give you a rough solution to this, but I warn you, this can be quite advanced Magento coding (depending on your skill-set), so be prepared.

Instead I'd follow this guide on overriding blocks.
http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

This does mean you'll need to create a module to handle this override. Not knowing more about your skill-set, it may be an idea to use a skeleton module for this, that way you'll know it's all set up and configured correctly.
http://www.mgt-commerce.com/kickstarter/

What you'll need to do is:

- Create an install a module from the kickstarter.
- Create a new block in your module that extends the class of `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Sales/Refunded/Grid.php` - this will immediately give you access to any of the methods contained within
- Add the code from the inchoo tutorial to your config.xml, ensuring the xml tags mirror the path to the file; you may want to check the Report module code to see if it matches correctly - I think the example in the tutorial overrides `Mage_Tag_Block_Product_List` so the xml tags that refer to `<tag>` and `<product_list>` will need to be changed to your needs.
- Override your methods (more information below).
- Save and clear cache.

**Your Solution**
To get this working with the information your require, you'll probably need to do the following:

- In `_prepareCollection()` ensure you have the total and subtotal as part of the object (if it isn't already) by executing a join or another custom function. You need each record to contain the existing data plus the subtotal and total.
- In `_prepareColumns()` add two new columns that had an index to the name of your subtotal and total columns

Comment: I try a few weeks ago this solution, don't able to do it (my skill are not here ^^), but previous solution wat to copy `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Sales/xxx/Grid.php` in `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Sales/xxx/Grid.php` and add in preparecollection and preparecolumn what I want, but there is not these function in `refunded/grid.php`. Thank's for your help, but I don't have the skill to do this for the moment =/